# Pspice AC analysis

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, buck, pspice, resonant-converter

I want to get the open loop transfer function bode plot of the converter. Here is my circuit:-

[image]

[image]

The pins of the CCM-DCM1 model are:-
1 - NMOS Drain

2 - NMOS Source

3 - Diode Cathode

4 - Diode Anode

5 - duty cycle input

When I simulate this using the AC Sweep/Noise solver, I get the wrong plot, shown here:-
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If this is what I suppose, CCM-DCM1 looks like an average model and maybe the one I built or is it from CoPEC? Anyway, this is an average simulation so you can't have the comparator and PWL source like V4 to create the duty ratio. You need to replace this block by a gain whose value is \$\frac{1}{V_p}\$ with \$V_p\$ being the peak of the sawtooth waveform in your modulator. The output of this gain feeding the model cannot exceed 1 V (100% duty ratio) and must be clamped. And finally, as underlined by *a concerned citizen* what is the role of \$L_2\$?

Comment: @VerbalKint Oops, ma' bad, I meant the second inductor (I deleted my comment, it was misleading). I also meant `D1` and `C2` (I probably need a break); are they needed? Isn't the averaged model supposed to include their behaviour?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen in its simplest form, an averaged model does not include the drops of the MOSFET or the diode but some extensions certainly do. I have published both auto-toggling CCM-DCM versions based on the PWM switch. This is probably one of them here. But as you mention, cap. \$C_1\$ has nothing to do here unless some resonance effect is wanted. However, if this is the case, the classical averaged model is no longer appropriate.

Comment: @VerbalKint I just followed CU Boulder tutorials to make the averaged model. Yes, the D1 is not needed, I removed it. L2, C2 are for ZCS action. I changed the circuit and posted it Again.

Comment: I don't think you can add extra resonant components to an averaged model derived for a fixed-frequency and hard-switching transitions. As I said, you can't have comparator U2 and a sawtooth as they belong to a cycle-by-cycle model. Please replace them by a gain block whose value is \$\frac{1}{V_p}\$. Then, as a first experiment, simply bias pin 5 of the model (the duty ratio input) with a 1-V ac and 500-mV dc source (50% dc) and see if the bias points make sense (if \$V_{out}\$ is at a reasonable value, not 1 kV), check the ac response. Then close the loop if the open-loop is ok.

Comment: @VerbalKint Yes it worked! thank you.

Comment: This is cool, happy to read this! : )

Comment: @VerbalKint This switch models a mosfet and a diode; what change would I have to make in case I wanted the same analysis for a synchoronous buck with same MOSFETs used for switching? (I think replacing the diode with the same IRF640 would not require a different control ckt bcoz deadtime is negligible)Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how the model is made but I assume it takes the voltage at the diode node and weights it by (1-D). Therefore, you could certainly replace the diode by a MOSFET with a specific bias at its gate to mimic the application environment. You can take a look at a [paper](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/1805/articles/H2PToday1805_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) I published on the subject in [How2Power](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/index.php).

Comment: @VerbalKint could you check the edited question? I've included the model definition there

Comment: I would remove \$L_2\$ even if it plays no role in the dc bias point. Please update the schematic diagram with the reflected voltages. It is important to *always* check the values computed by the model. Ah, to graph the power stage response in your case, simply plot the output voltage, no need for a differential measurement considering the ground-referenced ac source: Vdb(out) if out is the node voltage across \$R_1\$ and it should do well!