# Bode plot of buck converter incorrect?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, buck, pspice, bode-plot

So this question is a bit related to [my other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/551057/pspice-ac-analysis) on using Pspice to get the required transfer function of the buck converter.

Here in this circuit I'm trying to get the open loop transfer function bode plot of the converter. As suggested by VerbalKint in the other question, I am using the dB(voltage) probe as shown (not using x,y points):-

[image]

And this is what I get :-
[image]

*The Pspice bode plot is wrong, since there should be an overshoot of nearly 32 dB at the resonant frequency 7.587 kHz, but here its all wrong.* : **An error I realized pretty late, I should be using the DCM buck transfer function**.

Here is the circuit with bias voltage display.

[image]

This is what I got on MATLAB using the **DCM Transfer function**:-
[image]

So it is still quite different, as from Pspice I get PM = 48.73 degrees at 89.03 kHz, very different from MATLAB.

**EDIT 1:-**
Here is the model definition for U3 used here:-
[image]

Comment: What is the computed dc point? Always check it first before considering any ac results.

Comment: I am not asking for the transient results but for the dc operating point computed prior to the ac analysis with the averaged model. OrCAD offers the ability to reflect the bias points to the schematic nodes once the ac analysis is done. This is a good practice to adopt for any ac analysis. If the dc operating points are wrong, SPICE can still deliver an ac response but it is likely to be garbage.

Comment: @SM32 Looks like trouble: the output voltage is not 200 V. Are there parameters to set in the model?

Comment: @VerbalKint did you mean the image I added showing the voltages at different nodes? Because I enabled the "bias voltage display" button, sorry if my question is silly, I'm new to Pspice simulations.here the output is not showing 200V, but the same thing in transient analysis did show 200V,so I can't get what's going wrong.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen The transient analysis circuit is giving me 200V, the values agree with the formulas too.I haven't added any parameters, I assigned them from the very beginning. I think it is going wrong in the way I'm using CCMDCM1; my actual circuit is a synchronous buck,but here it's a MOSFET & diode config.Would that be a problem?

Comment: @SM32 What I mean is if you check the model's properties, do you get some parameters that you need to fill up, first? Such as switching frequency, or the value of the inductor? I'm *not* talking about the inductor that's in the schematic. The `.AC` analysis relies on calculating the operating point, so if the `.OP` is wrong, the `.AC` is wrong. What you see in `.TRAN` may converge towards a 200 V output, but it may not be the correct convergence. You need to verify that `U3` doesn't have additional (or hidden) parameters to be set.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, good point! Of course, there are parameters to pass to the model so that it can compute the correct \$d_2T_{sw}\$ value for determining the toggling point between CCM and DCM: .SUBCKT CCM-DCM1 1  2  3  4 CTRL params: FS=100k L=75u. SM32, if you built your symbol correctly, you should be able to access these parameters and enter the correct values. There must be some default parameters for the inductor and frequency.

Comment: @VerbalKint and aconcernedcitizen, Yes I did change the switching frequency & L values in my definition, I've added it here. Just to see when the output would be 200V, I changed the Vdc of V2 - it gives 200V output at 0.16Vdc, but still gives same bode plot.

Comment: @SM32 Well, that's a bummer. I made it in LTspice and got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIKKR.png), and I had to set the duty cycle at 0.275 to get 200 V output. I can see the *subcircuit* has modified parameters, but does the *symbol* in the schematic have some others? If yes, those would override the ones defined in the subcircuit. Still, there should have been 200 V at the output for 0.5 V duty cycle. Where did you get the model from? If it's from the default libray, it should work. Not sure what to think at this time.

Comment: @VerbalKint Is the blue MATLAB bode plot wrong or the simulation wrong? Because this converter is working in DCM, that bit is okay in bias point display also (I think) bcoz Vout > 0.5*Vin...

Comment: Let me run a few sims and I'll post an answer. The Matlab plot is wrong as DCM does not show peaking but the phase response of PSpice is also weird : ) What transfer function (TF) you have for Matlab? You should use a TF for DCM and not for CCM, right?

Comment: @VerbalKint Yes I finally realized my mistake of using CCM instead of DCM tf in MATLAB pretty late(I even mentioned the overshoot -_-). I've edited my post to include the DCM bode plot, it's still quite different (& wrong too, judging by crossover frequency). Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have captured your circuit using the PWM switch model in voltage mode and its equivalent differently derived by the CoPEC authors. The circuit is shown below:

[image]

First you need to check the dc points and confirm that they are correct and similar between the models. Both circuits deliver 270-271 V which is ok for a 50% duty ratio. We can now ac sweep both circuits and check their frequency responses:

[image]

The control-to-output transfer functions are rigorously identical which confirms that models are ok. I prefer symbols where you see the internal arrangements, it is easier to check for mistakes later on in my opinion.

If I now apply the DCM formula that I have derived in my next book on small-signal modeling, the Mathcad sheet delivers a response similar to that of SPICE:

[image]

As you may know, I am releasing a new book on small-signal modeling of switching converters (TOC is [here](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/TOC%20smallsignal.pdf)) in which I derived many transfer functions. The one for the DCM buck operated in VM was originally derived [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.458.1345&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'm consistently getting the DCM transfer function wrong which is the source of my troubles, could you tell me the final transfer function you derived? I'm going wrong with the rc,rl,rdson.

Comment: I'm getting Phase Margin(PM) = 90.2 deg @ 82.2 kHz, which is a bit different from the Pspice results of PM = 86.338 deg @ 98.25 kHz. Unless this is acceptable, if you could please give me the final transfer function without the derivations also, it'd be great. In this TF, the far away pole hasn't been taken into account.

Comment: I have derived all 4 transfer functions of switching converters in my next book (see the [TOC](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/TOC%20smallsignal.pdf)). I'll try to disclose the control-to-output TF of the DCM VM buck tonight.

Comment: Yes,I've seen the TOC before also,it has a lot of important things! Thank you, the TF (expression in variables,i.e generalized) would be most helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately I'm still a bit stuck. I think denominator of wp1 is 1-M. Also, if M = Vo/Vin, what should be Duty cycle D? I mean, if I take D=M=0.5, I'm getting it wrong. I tried D = pulse width * frequency, but that's giving the wrong crossover frequency.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this is 1-M for fp1 and I will correct the equation. Regarding the duty ratio, it is 0.5 indeed but M=0.678 because the output voltage is 271 V in the adopted configuration.